# Delete file after a certain number of days?

Tags: server-side, backend, delete-file

I am making a web-app that auto-deletes an uploaded file after a certain number of hours since it has been uploaded. My question is, what would be the best backend way of implementing this?

Should I poll a folder for files older than X hours then call a script to delete those files? Since it is going to be a web-app, is there something server-side language that I could use for it?

Comment: I assume your using a database to store Metadata about the file? Including the file path? Store the upload timestamp as well and poll the database on an interval.  I made a lot of assumptions - - please update your question to clear them up!

Comment: The question is too generic, add more details, at the very least specifying which server-side stack you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple back end **shell script** scheduled as a **cronjob** every x minutes will do the job if files are stored directly on file system. If file references , locations etc are stored in DB with time stamp, same can be cleaned up with shell script cronjob too.

This is the way it was being done in one of my previous projects.

Comment: Would a shell script like this work, where any file older than 5 days would be deleted? 

"`find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;`"

Is there a way to poll a database with a shell script?

Comment: that should work but do verify output of find command separately as options supported by find command vary from system to system. Also, for db part, I am not sure but guess, if its allowed to have x minutes stale data then cron should clean up data at a frequency of less than x minutes. I mean, by increasing or decreasing cron run frequency, you can adjust the amount of stale data .